# How can I get all the words starting with {$ of a HTML page with php function

Tags: html

I want to retrieve all the words beginning with $ of my html page in an array.

HTML page content test.html

```
<p>{$Nom}</p>
<p>{$Prenom}</p>
<p>{$Adresse}</p>
<p>{$CP}</p>
<p>{$Ville}</p>
```

function PHP

```
$filename = "test.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$input = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$pattern = '/[$](\w+)/';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\$\w+/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Results displayed

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => $NOM [1] => $PRENOM [2] => $ADRESSE [3] => $CP [4] => $VILLE [5] => ) )

Desired results with duplication:

NOM
PRENOM
ADRESSE
CP
VILLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's a simpler way than doing what Ray told you. You can

```
$filename = "test.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$input = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$matches = array();

// see the important part is wrapping the \w+ inside ( )
preg_match_all('/\$(\w+)/', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

because wrapping something with () in Regex will actually return another array containing that part of match. So, another array will be returned containing the (\w+) parts of your string, meaning just the words. So now the above will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $Nom
            [1] => $Prenom
            [2] => $Adresse
            [3] => $CP
            [4] => $Ville
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nom
            [1] => Prenom
            [2] => Adresse
            [3] => CP
            [4] => Ville
        )

)
```

But don't forget that you now need the `$matches[1]`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Now to duplicate I have to use array_unique?
thank you

Comment: Duplicate? You mean to remove duplicates right? Yes. if you want to remove every duplicate values, use array unique on $matches[1]

Comment: I could really appreciate if you marked my answer as correct one :v

Answer (score 0):

sure, just do the following since you need them in array

```
     <?php 
    $filename = "test.html";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $input = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    $pattern = '/[$](\w+)/';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/\$\w+/', $input, $matches);

    $final_result  = array();
    $index=0;
    foreach($matches as $match){
    $final_result[$index] = str_replace('\$','',$match[$index]);
    $index++;
}
```